# List all the mondays of this month

Tags: bash, unix

I'm pretty new to bash and all the terminal in general - I've been messing around with cal and the date scripts wondering if there is anyway to list all the dates of monday of the current month . 
My thought process is going thru the cal command, listing out the dates and maybe cutting a column from that input. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `date` command. Print 10 mondays since month ago:

```
for x in $(seq 0 9)
do
    date -d "$x monday 5 week ago"
done
```

And grep only current month. Full command: `for x in $(seq 0 9); do; date -d "$x monday 5 week ago"; done | grep $(date +%b)`

Output:

```
Mon Jun  5 00:00:00 MSK 2017
Mon Jun 12 00:00:00 MSK 2017
Mon Jun 19 00:00:00 MSK 2017
Mon Jun 26 00:00:00 MSK 2017
```

Comment: GNU date only that. Not POSIX

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
$ cal
     June 2017
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

You can do:

```
$ cal | awk 'NF>5{print $2}'
Mo
5
12
19
26
```

If you want something that will support *any* day of cal, use the field width (gawk only this):

```
$ cal | gawk -v n=5 '
            BEGIN{
               FIELDWIDTHS = "3 3 3 3 3 3 3"
           }
           FNR>1{print $n}'
Th 
 1 
 8 
15 
22 
29
```

---

Or, as pointed out in comments:

```
$ ncal | awk '/^Mo/'
Mo     5 12 19 26
```

Comment: Probably `ncal | awk 'NR==2{$1="";print}'`? Anyhow, plus one for using `cal`

Comment: and I thought I was the only person that kept a calendar with `cal -3`...

Answer (score 0):

Combination of cal,cut commands to achieve the output.

```
cal -h| cut -c'4,5'
```

Remove the highlight and cut the characters which suits in the fields of monday.

```
ncal | sed -n '/^Mo/p'
```

The output as below:

```
Mo     5 12 19 26
```