# How to write a bash script code to display the dates of saturday and sunday of the current month

Tags: bash

I am trying to display the dates of the weekend of the current month. That is Saturday and Sunday, I tried using the cal command but no success. Please help.

Comment: This should help you on your way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622980/list-all-the-mondays-of-this-month

Comment: What is the "weekend of the current month"? There are multiple in each month. What did you try? What's the expected output? What did you get instead?

Comment: I mean whatever month I run the script in. Say I run the script in July, it will get the month of July. I used the cal method

cal | grep "^S."

Answer (score 1):

The format of `cal` is regular, so you can just `cut` the appropriate columns of the output of `cal`, where the `-m` option is to start the week on Monday, so that Saturday and Sunday are on the right most part of `cal`'s output:

```
cal -m | cut -b 16-20
```

Comment: Thank you... is there a way to display these dates in an mm/dd/yy format. What command can I use?

Comment: Not with the command I've shown. You might want to look at the comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

From `man cal`

```
NAME
     cal, ncal — displays a calendar and the date of Easter
...
     -M      Weeks start on Monday.
...
```

So the command is `ncal` and `tail` to get last 2 lines

```
$ ncal -M | tail -2
Sa     7 14 21 28   
Su  1  8 15 22 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your "mm/dd/yy" formatting requirement, how about:

```
yy=$(date +%y)
mm=$(date +%m)
cal -m | cut -b 16-20 | awk -v yy="$yy" -v mm="$mm" '
NR>2 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf("%02d/%02d/%02d\n", mm, $i, yy)
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
03/01/20
03/07/20
03/08/20
03/14/20
03/15/20
03/21/20
03/22/20
03/28/20
03/29/20
```

(Based on Enrico's cool answer)